# safari html5 video loading issue

Tags: html, video, safari, html5-video

I'm having an issue with html5 video and safari 5. It works locally, the video pulls up and everything is fine. It will also pull up on the server if I go directly to the video path. Im just using the video tag and loading a video. It works on the server in all other browsers supporting html5 video. It works locally. It just doesn't work in safari on the server. In the network panel it shows the video trying to load but returns a null 404. The path to the video is relative. I'm very confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your markup and have you added the MIME types to your server's configuration file (e.g. to .htaccess?)

Comment: An example with URL to the video and the actual HTML code would be helpful. With this much of information the question is not very answerable. We cannot magically guess what's going on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem very similar to yours. HTML5 video/Safari working locally but not when published on server. First check your .htaccess file. You may need to modify MIME types. Here is a very good tutorial: [Dive into HTML5 Video](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html).
Second, and this solved my problem, are you serving from a protected site? The solution for me was to move video and audio files to an unprotected folder and then use an absolute path to the specific media.